# bootstrap toggle menu direction

Tags: bootstrap-4, navbar

when menu displayed on widescreen I need it like this:
Navbar Menu3 Menu2 Menu1

I'm trying to change direction when menu toggled
Navbar
Menu1
Menu2
Menu3

and NOT like this:
Navbar
Menu3
Menu2
Menu1

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark indigo">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02"
    aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu3 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

any idea how I can do it?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Basically the idea is to set the flex direction when the menu items are displayed as flex-column to its reverse, i.e., `flex-direction: column-reverse;`.

You can write your custom CSS to do so, but then you need to hard code the break point your navbar expands/collapses. The best way to do instead is just to use Bootstrap built-in class: `flex-column-reverse flex-lg-row` on the `navbar-nav`.

```css
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-lg-0 flex-column-reverse flex-lg-row">
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu3 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>

...
```

That would match your `navbar-expand-lg`, and whenever you decide to change it, you just need to remember to change `flex-lg-row` class as well.

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/wj7dLrsp/6/